# rails form_for another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a book class and want a user to update its rank. The code for the method in books_controller is:

```
def update_book_rank
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @book.rank = @book.rank + params[:rank]
  if @book.update!(book_params)
    redirect_to view_books_books_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

and the corresponding html.erb:

```
<h1>Adding rank to a book</h1>
<p>Name of the book: <%= @book.title %></p>
<p>Author of the book: <%= @book.author.name %></p>
<p>Please rank the book from 0(worst rating) to 10(best rating):</p>
<%= form_for @book, :url => update_book_rank_books_path, :method => :patch do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :rank %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :rank %>
  </p>

  <%= f.submit "Enter rank" %>
<% end %>
```

The following error occurs:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#update
Couldn't find Book with id=update_book_rank 
Extracted source (around line #25):
24 def update
25 @book = Book.find(params[:id])
26 authorize! :read, @book
27 if @book.update!(book_params)
28 redirect_to @book

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"kRt2RWNlKyBqMnEvoloLyJLwWrhjM5k1n9sw93Ar7eY=",
 "book"=>{"rank"=>"10"},
 "commit"=>"Enter rank",
 "id"=>"update_book_rank"}
```

Comment: Your request is going to update action. Can you specify your routes for update_book_rank_books

Comment: update_book_rank_books GET    /books/update_book_rank(.:format) books#update_book_rank. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Here you have specified GET request type and in form you have specified patch method

Comment: Why not you just use update action just remoce url and method from form_for and change name of update_book_rank to update

Comment: thank you for using patch and not get in routes file. However, still does not work. i need to use another action and not update because the rank of the book must be the average of all user's rank. that is why i need to use another action and not update and that is why i use url parameter in form_for. can you please help me?

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: well, actually this problem was solved, however in the method 
  update_book_rank states the error: Couldn't find Book without an ID

Comment: You need to define route with post request type and use form_tag update_book_rank_books_path(:id => @book.id)